# When is a mechitza required at a meal?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, wedding, meal-seudah, mechitza-partition

### **According to the opinions which require Mechitzos by weddings.**

Why isn't there a requirement to have Mechitzos by any other Seudas Mitzvah?

For example, why isn't there a requirement that one have a Mechitza by a Shabbos Table, a Seder, etc.

Comment: similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/is-a-mechitza-required-for-dancing-at-jewish-weddings-why but not equal. My question **is only valid according to the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch and the Beis Shmuel who prohibit mixed seating by a Chasuna**

Comment: The wedding...ceremony?

Comment: Also can you edit in references for the Kitzur and Beit Shemuel?

Comment: @DoubleAA no, at the Seudah. That's why it says "any other Seudas Mitzvah".

Comment: @ ShmuelBrill, Btw, I read "Beis Shmuel" and my first thought was "Sam's Club?".

Comment: @HodofHod I agree that's what he probably intended. But he should write it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a a private Shabbos Seuda and a wedding. By a private Seuda there usually is only family, however at a wedding you also invite others. Incidentally the Chasidim when they have a Mitzva Tantz and only the family remains, they take away the Mechitza. And when they make a Shabbos Sheva Brachos where there are others present back comes the Mechitza.